# How to create a register form for Users in Django

Tags: django

What is the Django way of creating a User?
I am not talking about the super user, just a simple form for users and creating an account

Comment: Do you mean a login form for existing users (as your title suggests) or a registration form for new users (as your question suggests)?

Comment: Users and authentication are all bound together, covered well in the docs.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/

Comment: I want a register form

Comment: [django-registration](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/index.html) could serve you as a good starting point

Answer (score 6):

The Django docs cover the topic of authentication quite well, and Django itself ships with views for login, logout, password change, and reset. For registration, you'll have to create your own view, something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("User created successfully!")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'auth/create_user.html', {'form': form})
```

This uses Django's built-in User creation form, which expects a username and two passwords, for verification. Your template would look something like this:

```
<form action='/create-user/' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What if I want my own registration form which takes date of email, date of birth, gender, country, etc. also? Not just username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Registration is not a part of Django framework, AFAIK. I can recommend `django-registration` (https://django-registration.readthedocs.io) application. It does require some custom template, but can save a lot of trouble with writing your own sign up views.