# how to create New user form in django Only those who have filled the my form, can enter my website

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hello i am new with Django an
i want to create a New User Form an Only those who
have filled the my form, can enter my website!

## My form required form fields

```
First Name
Last Nanme
EmailId
Mobile No
Broker
Address Field 1
Address Field 2
Address Field 3
City
State
PIN
AdhaarCard
PAN No
Bank Account No
Bank Name
Branch
```

Comment: I think this question help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/41433642/5747242   and also refer Django user  authentication : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/

Comment: am successfully create models for new user form an also create HTML template for it but i says in first i am just beginner with Django so i can't understand django.auth

Comment: in this link user not verified answer :(